# Index a boolean field as a string in sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have [a Ruby on Rails site](http://filmdev.org/) that uses thinking sphinx for searching a postgres database.

One of the fields in a table I am searching on is a boolean.
I'd like to be able to match on that boolean when a certain keyword is used in the search query.

To fully explain with an example:
My site is for people who develop their own black and white film.
I have a recipe table where people describe how they develop a film.  That table has a boolean column called "stand_developed" (a method of developing film).
I'd like to return results where that field is true when the user searches for the word "stand".

I've been through the [sphinx docs](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) and not really found if it's possible.

I guess I could hack something inside my controller method by parsing the query terms and adding a condition but is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution to this now.

I tried the "hack" I mentioned in my question - parsing the word "stand" and searching for it explicitly (a variation on the answer from Paul Davis) but it didn't work very well.

I didn't explain this in my question (didn't realise the full implications at the time I asked) but I need it to also match if the user used the word "stand" in their recipe description too.

So, I tried to get sphinx to add a condition along the lines of "if stand_developed is true or notes contains 'stand'" but I couldn't seem to find the right syntax for that.
It also had to deal with any other search text too.

In the end I added an extra column to my recipe table called "search_tags" and I add the word "stand" into it if the user selects "stand_developed" when adding a recipe.
I then get Sphinx to index that field as well as my other fields and it all works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done as far as searching on boolean fields using ThinkingSphinx. Pass `stand_developed` as a URL parameter along with your query_string in the following ways:

1. URL for a general query without search on `stand_developed` will be `http://yoursite.com/search?q=your_query_string`
2. URL for query with `stand_developed == TRUE` will be `http://yoursite.com/search?q=your_query_string&stand_developed=1`
3. URL for query with `stand_developed == FALSE` will be `http://yoursite.com/search?q=your_query_string&stand_developed=0`

Then, in your controller, you would do this:

```
if params[:stand_developed]  && params[:stand_developed].to_i == 1
  # perform query search with stand_developed == true
  @search_results = YourModel.search(params[:q], :with => {:stand_developed => true})
elsif params[:stand_developed]  && params[:stand_developed].to_i == 0
  # perform query search with stand_developed == false
  @search_results = YourModel.search(params[:q], :with => {:stand_developed => false})
else
  # perform general query search
  @search_results = YourModel.search(params[:q])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have just tested if params[:search] included the text 'stand' then done the searching from there. You don't need an extra column in your table, that's just overhead that's not needed.

```
if params[:search].downcase.include?('stand')
  Model.search params[:search], :with => {:stand_developed => true}
else
  Model.search params[:search]
end
```